# First character to speak only one word?

Tags: history-of

Hodor from Game of Thrones is the main character that comes to mind. He is only able to say a single word, which happens to be his name.

There are many other characters like these in the cinematic and literary universe. Where did this type of character come from? Who is the first character to only be capable of saying a single word?

Comment: Chewbacca?  "Rargh!".

Comment: See http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PokemonSpeak and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VerbalTicName (warning: TV Tropes links!)

Comment: Technically Groot says three words. *I am Groot.*

Comment: Shoot, I was just watching and I just heard him say Groot. Should have finished the movie before posting :P

Comment: In the first season of "Aeon Flux", Aeon uttered exactly one word: "Plop."

Comment: Hmmm... I just now realized that, as per the extant Close vote, this really is not geared to be pertaining to SF&F, but rather the "cinematic and literary universe".

Comment: Note that Hodor is not his real name, people call him that way *because* it's the only thing he says. I think he's really called Walder, but I can't check that at the moment.

Comment: There's also "Experts in the Field" by Christopher Anvil - from 1967, so maybe not the first, but not far from FuzzyBoots' answer.  Has visual telepaths, so they would send images... and to tell the recipient who was sending, the characters would each speak only one word (their own name).  The story was figuring this out, very fun.

Answer (score 13):

Certainly not the first, but one that significantly pre-dates Fuzzy's 1983: The Raven from Edgar Allen Poe's The Raven. It was only capable of saying "nevermore".

Comment: Good one. I was going to suggest Grog from B.C., originating in 1966, but you're already well past me.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Why did you delete your answer? :-( I would have upvoted that! It might not be as old as this Poe-m, but it's far more firmly within the realm of SFF.

Comment: @randal'thor: Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

As per the TVTropes link, I'm going to guess Errand from The Belgariad. His first appearance was *Magicians Gambit*, released in 1983.

If you include a comic-strip among the potential sources, Grog from [B.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.C._(comic_strip)) originated in 1966.